# How to define Pyodbc hive queue?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to connect to the Hive(cluster) via knox. i want my jobs to use a specific Tez queue. but its always end up in default queue as checked in resource manager.

I tried using tez.queue.name=myqueue, with connection_string

This is the snippet

```
my connect_string = Description=Knox DSN;Driver=/usr/lib/hive/lib/native/Linux-amd64-/libhortonworkshiveodbc64.so;Host=knox;port=8448;HttpPath=gateway/jgd/hive;ServiceDiscoveryMode=0;HiveServerType=2;AuthMech=3;SSL=1;KrbRealm=;KrbHostFQDN=;KrbServiceName=;AllowSelfSignedServerCert=1;CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=1;TrustedCerts=/usr/lib/hive/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/cacerts.pem;ThriftTransport=2;uid=myuid;pwd=mypass;Schema=mydb;tez.queue.name=myqueue


    My os = CentOS Linux release 7.2
    Python version = 2.7
    pyodbc.version ='3.0.0-unsupported'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put anything in spaces inbetweeen brackets.

```
Description={Knox DSN};Driver=/usr/lib/hive/lib/native/Linux-amd64-/libhortonworkshiveodbc64.so;Host=knox;port=8448;HttpPath=gateway/jgd/hive;ServiceDiscoveryMode=0;HiveServerType=2;AuthMech=3;SSL=1;KrbRealm=;KrbHostFQDN=;KrbServiceName=;AllowSelfSignedServerCert=1;CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=1;TrustedCerts=/usr/lib/hive/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/cacerts.pem;ThriftTransport=2;uid=myuid;pwd=mypass;Schema=mydb;tez.queue.name=myqueue
```